# How to identify Git object type based on its SHA1 code?

Tags: git

Given object's SHA1 code, how could one identify the object type (blob, tree, tag, or commit)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `git cat-file -t`, e.g.:

```
$  git cat-file -t ffcb14ca1dad
commit
$ git cat-file -t 74e34003a
blob
```

This use of `git cat-file` is explained in [its documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cat-file.html).